# Перестала работать база данных room, долго проект не запускал, вернулся к нему и пишет Unable to copy database file

Tags: java, база-данных, android-room, room

Когда запускал в последний раз не работала логика, а сейчас даже база данных не подгружается. Вот класс где она должна подгружаться:

```
package com.gorchatov.shazamclone;

import android.app.Application;

import androidx.room.Room;

public class App extends Application {
private static App instance;

private MusicDatabase musicDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
    musicDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(this, MusicDatabase.class, "Music")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .createFromAsset("database/myfin.db")
            .build();//сюда надо путь к готовой БД
}

public static App getInstance() {
    return instance;

}

public MusicDatabase getDatabase() {
    return musicDatabase;
}}
```

вот где приложение вылетает:

```
dataBaseThread = new Thread(() -> {
        musicDao = App.getInstance().getDatabase().musicDao();
    });
    dataBaseThread.start();
    musicDao.getAll();
```

Ошибка

> 023-05-27 20:14:11.876 25223-25272 AndroidRuntime          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: AudioRecorder Thread
> Process: com.gorchatov.shazamclone, PID: 25223
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to copy database file.
> at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.verifyDatabaseFile(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.kt:114)
> at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.kt:68)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:638)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:457)
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MusicDao_Impl.getAll(MusicDao_Impl.java:131)
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MainActivity.RecognizeMusic(MainActivity.java:240)
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MainActivity.writeAudioDataToByte(MainActivity.java:139)
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$com-gorchatov-shazamclone-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:88)
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
> Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
> at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:203)
> at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(FileChannelImpl.java:364)
> at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(FileChannelImpl.java:756)
> at androidx.room.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.kt:41)
> at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.copyDatabaseFile(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.kt:179)
> at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.verifyDatabaseFile(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.kt:111)
> at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.kt:68) 
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:638) 
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:457) 
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MusicDao_Impl.getAll(MusicDao_Impl.java:131) 
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MainActivity.RecognizeMusic(MainActivity.java:240) 
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MainActivity.writeAudioDataToByte(MainActivity.java:139) 
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$com-gorchatov-shazamclone-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:88) 
> at com.gorchatov.shazamclone.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2) 
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, файл базы данных был поврежден. Попробуйте создать новый файл базы данных и перенести данные из старого файла в новый.

Comment: Пересоздал базу данных, не помогло